# MySQL SELECT query to create ladder in sports competition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a sports fixture and ladder for a sports competition. I am having trouble creating the ladder.

I would like the ladder to look something like [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1859080/ladder.png). Teams get 2 points for a win or bye and 1 point for a draw.

And I would like to create that ladder using a table that looks like [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1859080/table.png)

This is as far as I have gotten, but it only returns the names of teams who have won a game and how many games they have won:

```
SELECT teamname,COUNT(*) as wins 
FROM result where pointsfor > pointsagainst and completed = "1" 
GROUP BY teamname ORDER BY wins DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using subqueries like this:

```
SELECT
    teamname,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM result WHERE teamname = r.teamname AND pointsfor > pointsagainst AND completed = 1) AS wins,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM result WHERE teamname = r.teamname AND pointsfor < pointsagainst AND completed = 1) AS losses,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM result WHERE teamname = r.teamname AND pointsfor = pointsagainst AND completed = 1) AS draws
FROM result AS r
GROUP BY teamname
ORDER BY wins DESC
```

Edit: Added Group by